# Change Values in Select List based on button toggle

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to change the values in a select list (populated from a JSON object through JQuery) based on the toggle of several buttons (bootstrap buttons) (which can be turned on and off)

so far I have something like this:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="Toggle1">Toggle1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="Toggle2">Toggle2</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="Toggle3">Toggel3</button>
</div>

<script>
$.post("/getResults", {"inputParam" : param}, function (data) {
var options = $("#selectlist");
$.each(data, function () { options.append($('<option />').text(this.Name).val(this.id)); });

$(function () {
   $('#toggle1').on('click', function () {
        rePopSelect("toggle1-" + $(this).hasClass('active'));
     });

$('#toggle2').on('click', function () {
        rePopSelect("toggle2-" + $(this).hasClass('active'));
     });

$('#toggle3').on('click', function () {
        rePopSelect("toggle2-" + $(this).hasClass('active'));
     });
</script>
```

I'm stuck on writing the function `rePopSelect()` seems like it would be better to store the results of the `$.post` in an object and then use the results of the toggle to just rebuild the entire select list based on some filter criteria from the toggles, but I am not sure how to do this.

An example of the JSON is below:

```
[{"id":1,"Name":"Blah-Blah","Type":"H"},{"id":2,"Name":"Blah-Blah2","Type":"C"}]
```

Basically toggle1, should select only H, toggle2, should select only C, toggle3 should select only S(in this example...that means nothing)

Note that a combination of toggles can be selected, so if both toggle1 and toggle2 are selected, in this example that would be the entire set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revised my answer. Not tested but should get you close.

Something like:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="Toggle1" add="H">Toggle1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="Toggle2" add="C">Toggle2</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="Toggle3" add="S">Toggel3</button>
</div>

var options;
$.post("/getResults", {"inputParam" : param}, function (data) {
   options = data;
});


$('.btn').click(function(){

   if ($(this).attr("on")=="true") {
       $(this).attr("on","false");
   } else {
       $(this).attr("on","true");
   }

   $("#selectID option").remove();

   $('button[on=true]').each(function(){
       addkey = $(this).attr("add");
       options.each(function(){
           if (this.Type == addkey) {
              $('#selectID').append('<option value="'+this.id+'">'+this.Name+'</option>');
           }
       });


   });
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand, but it seems like that will query again, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: Do you have the function started?  What does your JSON look like?

Comment: No, I haven't started the function but I edited the question to include example JSON.

Comment: see above... like I said, not tested but should get you close.

Comment: heathhettig is a jQuery ninja!

Comment: Actually, I'm a bit stuck and getting an error around addKey = $(this).attr('id')...it is always undefined